# maven settings.xml pull environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-cli

https://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/07/maven-repository-amazon-s3.html

How can I get this to look at my environment variable instead of static config?

Can I set a role profile in the maven config too? my credentails file has a role setup that can be assumed

Comment: Simple answer: You can't use environment variables at the moment cause it's not supported.

Comment: Is there a way to execute a command in the xml? Can I have it execute a command to get the keys and sts keys? also how can I get it too assume a role? I only have keys for access to other resources I need to use the user for those keys to assume a role with the right bucket access

Comment: ${env.VARIABLE_NAME} doesn't work?